# find the longest sequence of consecutive numbers in decreasing order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list [5,2,7,4,3,2,0,8, 9,100,99,98,97,93,92]
i need out [100,99,98,97]
but i am getting 4, 3, 2, 100, 99, 98, 97, 93, 92

```
`arr=[5,2,7,4,3,2,0,8, 9,100,99,98,97,93,92]
 z=[]
 l=[]
 for i in range(len(arr)-1):

      if(arr[i]==arr[i+1]+1):
            if(arr[i] not in z):
                z.append(arr[i])
            if(arr[i+1] not in z):
                z.append(arr[i+1])
      print(z)`
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review StackExchange! Unfortunately, broken code is off-topic here. Please see the [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your algorithm is flawed.

you need to reset the array when you start a new sequence. keep a record of the current longest sequence so you can work out which is longest

```
import copy
arr=[5,2,7,4,3,2,0,8,9,100,99,98,97,93,92]
z = []
l = []

for i in range(1, len(arr)):
  l.append (arr[i-1])
  print(arr[i-1])
  while( i < len(arr) and arr[i-1] - 1 == arr[i]):    
    l.append(arr[i])  
    print(arr[i])
    i=i+1
  if(len(l) > len(z)):  
    print("clear")  
    z = z.clear()
    z = copy.copy(l)  
  l.clear()
print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the algorithm is:
1. there is no logic that recognizes the ending of the on-going consecutive decreasing sequence.
2. there is no logic that compares candidate sequences and tracks the longer one.

If we walk through the code, we can see it encounters a sequence of `4,3,2` starting from 4th iteration and then it encounters a sequence of `100,99,98,97`. So the output is expected.

An example of working code:

```
arr=[5,2,7,4,3,2,0,8, 9,100,99,98,97,93,92]
longest = []
current = []
i = 0
if len(arr < 2):
    print(arr)
    return

while i < len(arr)-1:
   current.append(arr[i])
   j = i + 1
   while j < len(arr) and arr[i] == arr[j] + j-i:
      current.append(arr[j])
      j += 1

   i = j # start a new sequence at index j 

   if len(current) > len(longest):
       longest = current
   current = []

print(longest)
```

There are definitely better ways to implement this in idiomatic python but hopefully, the code above illustrates the algorithm.